# Angularjs2 how to close streaming session

Tags: html, angular, streaming

I am using AngularJS2 and also using router function to show user streaming ip cameras. The problem is whenever user uses router function(This means webpage is not refreshed) sockets are being held and after few times it reaches to the browser socket limitation(Chrome is 6) and user can't see cameras anymore. My plan is just close socket when user uses router function but i am not sure this is a good solution. Please let me know how to close socket or solve this problem without refresh.

Comment: Show some code to people can help you, you question is unclear.

Comment: I want to show you my code but it's too much to post here. And I think this issue can be explained without code.

Comment: If you think that you have too much code to post it here, create a plunker.

Comment: Let me think about that if i can't get any answers.